# Changing size of linked Table of Contents from Word to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a Table of Contents in Word that I've linked to an Excel document. It works great, updates appropriately except for one problem. If I have a section in my Table of Contents, let's say 11.1, and I add 11.2 to the ToC then my link in Excel will not update appropriately because the array size has changed. Is there any way to allow the array size to change to update appropriately? When I add a section to the end of a ToC it won't show up in the update at all, but if I add it before the end the last entry of the ToC disappears. Also, if I remove a section from the ToC, then in Excel the last row shows 0's. I really hope this is possible!